# How to write in a different div after character count

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter, word-count

How can I implement a feature so that upon passing a character count limit, you start typing in a different div automatically?

For example, if there were two div ids like the following:

```
<div id="from" contenteditable="true"></div>
<div id="to" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

How can you implement something so that after writing 140 characters in "from" div, your content is translated and displayed inside `to` div? My guess was:

```
var text = document.getElementById('from').textContent.substr(140, 1000)
```

And then adding this text variable inside the htmlcontent of `to` div class. However, by doing this the html text is being written in both the `from` and `to` div class. I would like to be automatically typing inside the `to` div after the 140 character limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following should work for what you are asking

```js
$("#from").focus();
$("#from").keypress(function(){
    if($("#from").html().length === 140){
        $("#to").focus();
    }
});
$("#to").click(function(e){
    f = $("#from");
    t = $("#to");
    if(t.html().length === 0 && f.html().length !== 140){
        fto()
    }
});
$("#to").keydown(function(e){
    f = $("#from");
    t = $("#to");
    if(t.html().length <= 1 && (e.keyCode === 8 || e.keyCode === 46)){
        e.preventDefault();
       if(t.html().length === 1){
            t.html('');
       }
        fto();
    }
});

function setCursorToEnd(ele){
    var r = document.createRange();
    var s = window.getSelection();
    r.setStart(ele, 1);
    r.collapse(true);
    s.removeAllRanges();
    s.addRange(r);
    ele.focus();
}
function fto(){
    f = $("#from");
    if(f.html().length === 0){
        f.html(' ');//error occurs if from has no length
    }
    setCursorToEnd(f.get(0));
    if(f.html() === ' '){
     f.html('');//return to empty
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="from" contenteditable="true"></div>
<div id="to" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

is this what you looking for?

```
<div id="from" contenteditable="true"></div>
<div id="to" contenteditable="true"></div>
<script>
var from = document.getElementById("from");
var to = document.getElementById("to");
from.onkeypress = function(){
    if(from.textContent.length==140)
        to.focus();
}
</script>
```